# Login issue in 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login, tty

I update 16.04 and I don't remember my username, can't open my computer how to know username please help. 
I tried press and hold shift that didn't work, i also tried clrt+alt+f7 in that screen disappeared.

Please help

Comment: Perhaps better to reinstall, don't you think so?

Answer (score 0):

In addition to learning username with above explanation you want to be eager how to recovery your "lost" password by this article.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LostPassword

Because, as i see your question , "what about password" come my mind.

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

To find your username...

- boot to the GRUB menu
- choose Advanced Options
- choose Recovery mode
- choose Root access
- at the # prompt, type `ls /home`
- your username, and possibly other usernames, will appear in that list
- at the # prompt, type `reboot`